# Put javascript code in HTML View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following Partial View Code:

```
@using HTML5_Application_Instances;
@using System;
@using ADIGITALBOOK_HTML5_INIT.Helpers;
@using adigitalbook.html5.mainserver.Helpers;
<script>
    function OSPIntegrationVars() { }
    OSPIntegrationVars.OSPController = '@Html.Raw(ItemsHelper.BaseURL + Url.Action("Index", "OSP"))';
    OSPIntegrationVars.elementID = '@ItemsHelper.elementID';
</script>

@Scripts.Render(BundlesVirtualPaths.OSP)
```

The last line is render scripts by create a couple of scripts tags that contains the src property that is pointing to each script file.

Instead have tags pointing to scripts, what i want is render the code of each file "like a string" for the browser interpret the JavaScript code at the same time as are interpreting the html code.

It's a little complicated to explain, so if you have any question to made, please ask.

*[EDIT: REASON BEHIND THE PROBLEM]*

The reason it is simple: What i'm doing is calling the view expose by doing an ajax call with the propose to append the html to a page. Because the render of scripts it is using the src property it will make the load of file asynchronous. What i really want it made the step synchronous by having the javascript code directly in the html that the ajax call receive.

Comment: You want it to render the javascript code from within the file on the html page directly? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I understand the question, you want to embed the Javascript into the HTML document. Why?

Comment: Regardless of your rationale behind wanting to do this, it's simply not possible. You can't render a bundle as inline JavaScript, only as a `script` tag pointing to the bundle file.

Comment: Why? If you need to debug, there are better ways to do that. Please tell us why you want to do this and maybe we can help you with a workaround.

Comment: See the post edit for more information. Chris Pratt, or you and I didn't understand each other or what you are said is not true because I already implemented and it is working fine